# AWS Backup Storage and Storgae from for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can any one help me storing the rails backup on AWS Backup storage service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking the Database then [DB2fog](https://rubygems.org/gems/db2fog) should do the trick:

**Config**

```
DB2Fog.config = {
  :aws_access_key_id     => 'yourkey',
  :aws_secret_access_key => 'yoursecretkey',
  :directory             => 'bucket-name',
  :provider              => 'AWS'
}
```

**Usage**

```
# Add to your crontab or whatever
rake db2fog:full

# Handy tasks
rake db2fog:restore  # You should be testing this regularly
rake db2fog:clean    # Clean up old backups - cron this
```

or from inside Ruby:

```
DB2Fog.new.backup
DB2Fog.new.clean
```

Comment: For entire rails project files